# How to tell if `CLUSTER table USING index` finished?

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, clustered-index

I want to use an AWS scheduled Lambda function to update my PostgreSQL table indexes every month. I am not on `psql` bash and I am not leaving Lambda function up until `CLUSTER` finishes.

How can I tell if the `CLUSTER` finished?

Answer (score 2):

To find out whether or not you have any executing `CLUSTER` commands, simply run this..

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE query ~ '^CLUSTER'
  AND state = 'active';
```

However, that doesn't tell you if it already finished on a table. I don't think you can figure that out. You can only see

- whether or not a `CLUSTER` is running.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity AS psa
  WHERE query ~* '^CLUSTER'
    AND state = 'active';
  ```
- if one is currently running, what table it was running on. This requires more work, we look at the locked tables the transaction is using to figure this out.

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM pg_stat_activity AS psa
  JOIN pg_locks AS pl
    ON (pl.pid = psa.pid)
  WHERE query ~* '^CLUSTER'
    AND state = 'active'
    -- replace with table
    AND relation::regclass = 'MyTable'::regclass
    AND mode = 'AccessExclusiveLock';
  ```